# Scala add Serializable to package-private Java class

Tags: java, scala, serialization, guava

How can I make a package-private Java class serializable? I tried creating a serializable version of Guava's ImmutableRangeMap by creating a new class with the package set to `com.google.common.collect` like so:

```
package com.google.common.collect
class SerializableImmutableRangeMap[K, V](ranges: ImmutableList[Range[K]], values: ImmutableList[V]) extends ImmutableRangeMap[K, V](ranges, values) with Serializable;
```

However, I get compilation errors (`not found: value SerializableImmutableRangeMap`) when I try to use my class:

```
var ranges = SerializableImmutableRangeMap.builder[T, String]()
```

What's the proper way to make this `Serializable`?

Comment: I am not a scala programmer, but: surely the point of a package private class (and one whose Immutability is only guaranteed by its implementation) is that you aren't meant to extend it.

Comment: But the actual problem that you're having here, I think, is that you're invoking the static `builder` method on `ImmutableRangeMap`, since you haven't provided an implementation to build a Serializable* instance.